# FOSRestBundle how to use forms to CRUD entities that require relationships?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, fosrestbundle

Super simple example:

```
[Album] 1 --> 0..n [Song]
```

Which means that while `[Album`] can have exactly zero `[Songs]`, every `[Song]` require related `[Album]`.

I use nested resources so my routing.yml look like this:

```
albums:
  type:rest
  resource: ...

songs:
  type: rest
  parent: albums
  resource: ...
```

1. **How do I create form for Song that will validate presence of existing Album?**
2. **How will related JSON look like?**

Symfony 2.7
FOSRest 1.7

Answer (score 2):

Try doctrine:generate:crud (more details http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_crud.html)

This command generate controller with CRUD, forms and views. But you can customize, what you want to get.

Related entities will also looks like array. For example, you try to output songs, then json will be like below:

```
[{..., name: "Song1", album:{"id": 1, "name": "Album"}}]
```

Btw, to output this using querybuilder you need to innerJoin relationship like below:

```
$qb->select('s', 'album')
    ->innerJoin('s.album', 'album')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getArrayResult(); // or ->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

Comment: That's for 1. Any help with 2. How should that JSON look like?

Comment: Now I see it. Symfony Form do not care if there are any relations. Its all handled by AlbumType and SongType. Thx!

Comment: Unfortunatly generate:crud do not handle putAction :\ which I would like to use accordingly to FOSRest bundle.

Comment: @przemo_li add your putAction to your question.